Validity of limit proofs by forcing an absolute value of a difference to go to $0$
I was working through a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Then
$$F(x)=\int^x_af(t) dt$$
is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and the derivative at $x$ is $f(x)$.

The proof considers the right derivative first, taking $h>0$ and $x$ to be a fixed number in $[a,b]$. Then
$$\left| \int^{x+h}_x \frac{f(t)}{h} dt - f(x) \right| = \left| \int^{x+h}_x \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{h} dt \right|$$
$$\le \max_{t\in[x,x+h]}{|f(t)-f(x)|}$$
This right hand side goes to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$, so
$$\lim_{h\to0+} \left| \int^{x+h}_x \frac{f(t)}{h} dt -f(x)\right| = 0$$
and $F^\prime_+(x)=\lim_{h\to0+}\int^{x+h}_x\frac{f(t)}{h}dt=f(x)$.
I think I've seen this technique used a lot before, but is this valid? My book says that if $\lim g(x) = L$, then $\lim |g(x)| = |L|$, but this is going in reverse, isn't it? In order to move the limit into the absolute value, we need to know that the limit of the inside exists. That is, we need to know $\lim_{h\to0+}\int^{x+h}_x \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{h} dt$ exists. But how?

The fact that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left|\int_x^{x+h}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{h}\,\mathrm dt\right|=0$$
can be showed by Sandwich Theorem which says

If $f\leq g\leq h$ on a deleted neighbourhood of $a$ and
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}h(x)$$
Then, $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists and is equal to the limit above.

For your second part, in general it is not true that if $\lim_{x\to a}|g(x)|=L$ then $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\pm L$. But if $L=0$, then that means for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\implies\big||g(x)|-0\big|\leq\varepsilon$$
The latter inequality can be written as $|g(x)-0|\le\varepsilon$, and so the limit of $g(x)$ is simply $0$.
Hope this helps. :)

Great answer. Is the sandwich theorem something that I might know by a different name? Is it ever called the squeezing theorem or is this totally different?

@RedFive: Yeah, it has several names. Squeezing theorem might be one of them, I'm aware of Squeeze theorem.
